# FIle Upload in WebdriverIO with AutoIT

Tags: javascript, autoit

I am trying to upload a file in a file upload filed in WebdriverIO with AutoIT. I am unable to execute the .exe file which will select the file from File Explorer in Windows. Can anyone tell me what is the mistake in the code?

```js
    var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
    /**
    * Function to execute exe
    * @param {string} fileName The name of the executable file to run.
    * @param {string[]} params List of string arguments.
    * @param {string} path Current working directory of the child process.
     */
    function execute(fileName, params, path) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(imup.exe, params, { cwd: "F:\\imup.exe" }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data);
        });

    });
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: whats the error

Comment: Not getting any error. But, the .exe file is not executing. Not sure if WebdrvierIO executed the file.